# ASP.NET Core MVC : once I have published a project, how do I force migrations to update to the database?

Tags: asp.net-core, publishing

I have a project I have been working on in ASP.NET Core MVC, and now that I have published it:

[image]

I want to be able to force all migrations onto the database active on our server (my local database is just a copy so naming and table names and etc are the same).

Once I copy across the files to the server folder and run it, currently none of the migrations update the database and I get missing columns and tables and etc errors.

I have tried using cmd on the published file with

```
dotnet AppName.dll database update
```

as many people have suggested, but this didn't work at all. It doesn't seem to read the command at all.

[image]

Can someone please give me one straight answer? I have been struggling to find an answer that doesn't explain what to do or has old no longer working methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
```

in your StartUp.Configure.
This will display the Apply Migrations Page you know from Developing.

Another way would be to create a migration script in development and use it against the production database. You can create an idempotent script with cmd while being in the Project Directory (where the StartUp.cs is located).

```
dotnet ef migrations script --output "migration.sql" --idempotent
```

This will create a script (a new file migration.sql) that will take any database that is on a prior level in the migration history to the current level.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had to update my netcoreapp to 3.1 and had to add a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore to use app.UseDatabaseErrorPage() due to it being in it's own package now. But the first option worked perfectly. I just ran the sql script after and tada. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 1):

You might generate a script of your migrations and install the script on your deployment environment. The advantage is you can store the migration scripts for example in a folder and keep track of what has been installed or what needs to be installed in the next release.

A migration script is generated with command `Script-Migration`:

```
Script-Migration -From <PreviousMigration> -To <LastMigration>
```

Be sure to check the [EF Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#script-migration) (Entity Framework Core tools reference) before you run the script.